# Why does the fold method give the actual element instead of a reference?

Tags: rust

According to the [rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/iterators.html) for iterators there are consumers like `find` and `fold`.

They are used as:

```
let greater_than_forty_two = (0..100).find(|x| *x > 42);
```

and

```
let sum = (1..4).fold(0, |sum, x| sum + x);
```

In both cases `x` is the current value. However in the first case `x` is a reference and in the second case it is the element itself.

As far as I understood from the `for` loop, it has to be a reference to avoid owner problems. But shouldn't there be the same owner problem in the fold case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is somewhat hard to explain with integers, since they are `Copy`, so compare:

```
let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];
let result = v.into_iter().find(|s| s.starts_with("b"));
result == Some("b".to_string())

let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];
let result = v.into_iter().fold("".to_string(), |a, s| s + &a);
result == "ba".to_string()
```

In the first case, the `String` needs to be returned to the caller, so we can't have the closure destroy it (which would happen if it was passed by value). In the second, the values are no longer used after the call to the closure, so they can be passed to the closure by value (which allows us to consume the `String` when we append to it).

Comment: Ok, the point is, that `find` actually returns one of its values, while `fold` always returns a new (composed) value. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it really inefficient to fold iterables of large structs then? I'm quite new to Rust.